# predict sold/not sold using a feature that is only applicable to 100% sold

Tags: regression, probability, descriptive-statistics

so here is an example of what i'm trying to do. suppose this is cell phones: From a sales standpoint, there is Quotes, sales, and upgrades.

if I want to predict sales (sold/not sold), I can use my **quote** leads and do a model on probability of sold/not sold. if I want to predict who upgraded their product, I can use my **sold** data and predict upgrade/no upgrade.

What if, I want to predict the following: What impact does upgrades have on my conversion(sold/not sold)? I cant model sold/not sold using upgrades because all upgrades are "sold". I'm trying measure if high rate of upgrade also means high rate of conversion, etc etc

Comment: What is the meaning of "upgrades" and what is it's relationship to the "sold" value?

Comment: so for example:  a sales person will try to sell a phone to a customer.  If they buy the phone, it is "sold.".  Later, they can decide to "upgrade" their phone to another version.  every phone that is sold has the chance to be upgraded, but not all sold phones will upgrade

Comment: I don't know about this topic, but it seems that conversions necessarily follow sales. Therefore, it seems impossible that conversions could affect, or be used to predict sales. Am I understanding this correctly? I'd be interested to hear if you have a theory for how conversions affect sales.

Comment: I think my initial post was confusing as I used conversions and sales in the same sentence.  Forget about conversion and lets say I'm just predicting 0/1 (not sold/sold).  I'm trying to understand how upgrades/no upgrades have on sales/no sales. of All my solds, I can predict who will upgrade/not upgrade.  but i'm trying to see if there is a relationship between people who upgrade vs people who are sold the product.  My initial hypothesis is that people who tend to ugprade are also the same people who are more likely to buy in the first place.  But that is just a hunch...